# Did I create N-gons?

Tags: geometry

I have modelled an oven.

The front has some details, but the back should be plain as nobody will see it.

To remove unnecessary geometry from the back, I select it, then choose "Dissolve Faces".

[image]

[image]

This looks good to me, but I am afraid that I might have created N-gons.
How could I check if I did that?

Thank you!

Comment: yes the face on the right is a ngon as it has more than 4 vertices, ngons are not always problem though, it really depends on what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you created an ngon in the back. Being that It's in the back maybe it's not a problem. If you are encountering a problem a very easy thing to try is to inset the ngon face which gives you quads around the perimeter of the ngon which will solve some problems. If you want to rework your topology so that you don't have ngons or unnecessary geometry on the sides without detail I recommend watching this video which shows how to step down your faces while maintaining quad geometry: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGL6QpVRyXk&list=PL0v8ug1WwacVeXGNVRHexenYbip_7LMPD&index=19&ab_channel=DECODED